# How to solve the following equation: $a(x^2 (x-1)b+c) = d x(1-x e) f^{x-1}$

Tags: calculus, functions, inequality

Please, I need to solve the following equation (w.r.t. $x$):

$a(x^2 (x-1)b+c) = d x(1-x e) f^{x-1}$, where $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$, $f$ are positive constants  and $x \ge 1$ .

( I am trying to solve this inequality: $a(x^2 (x-1)b+c) > d x(1-x e) f^{x-1}$. )

Comment: If you want to provide values for the constants, I shall try to show you how this could be done using numerical methods.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Let us take $a=0.9$, $b=20$, $c=1000$, $d=800$, $e=0.01$ and $f=0.93$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let consider the function using the numbers you gave in your comments; so $$f(x)=0.9 \left(20\, (x-1) \,x^2\,+1000\right)-800  \,(1-0.01 x) \,x\,\,0.93^{x-1}$$ If you plot the function for $0 \leq x \leq 20$, you notice that there is a solution close to $x=1$ and another one close to $x=5$ (by the way, there is another solution close to $x=-10$).

Let us focus on the solution close to $x=5$ and use Newton root-finding method : if you already know, starting from a "reasonable" estimate of the solution $x_0$, the method will update it according to $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ So, in the case we consider, using $x_0=5$, the following iterates will sucessively be : $5.17023$, $5.16119$, $5.16117$ which is the solution for six significant figures.

For illustration, starting instead iterations at $x_0=10$, the iterates would be $7.31805$, $5.86244$, $5.27590$, $5.16513$, $5.16117$.

For sure, we could do the same for the solution close to $x=1$ but we can obtain something good using series (as mentioned by JJacquelin). Built at $x=1$, Taylor series would be $$f(x)= 108.-708.524 (x-1)+98.8099 (x-1)^2+O\left((x-1)^3\right)$$ Solving the quadratic would give $x\approx 1.15582$ while, using Newton, the solution would be $1.15590$.

Doing the same building the series at $x=5$, we would have $$f(x)=-142.598+837.692 (x-5)+289.586 (x-5)^2+O\left((x-5)^3\right)$$ and the solution of the quadratic would be $x\approx 5.16124$. Not too bad, isn't it ?

I hope and wish that this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The equations on the form 
$$P(X)=Q(X)C^X$$
with polynomials $P(X), Q(X)$ and constant $C$, cannot be solved analytically for $X$ , except in some very simple cases. (In understanding "solved" as expressing the solution with a finite number of referenced elementary and/or special functions).

For example, if $P(X)=X$ and Q(X)=1, the solution of the equation $X=C^X$ involves a special function called the Lambert W function.

Approximates of the solution can be expressed on the form of series and more commonly in practice, by numerical methods of computation.